# OS X Terminal: tr: how to add multiple carriage returns?

Tags: macos, terminal, newline, carriage-return, tr

I have a file that is formatted like this:

```
> ABC
1
2
> DEF
3
4
```

I would like to use tr to replace each `>` with 4 carriage returns, so it looks like:

```
 ABC
1
2




 DEF
3
4
```

I tried the following in the Terminal: `cat input | tr ">" "\n\n\n\n" > output`
However, this only adds one carriage return between the two blocks of data, like this:

```
 ABC
1
2

 DEF
3
4
```

How can I get it to recognize the multiple carriage returns? Thanks!

Comment: In unix-format text files (which you seem to be dealing with), line breaks are represented by linefeeds (aka newlines or `/n` or `^J`), not carriage returns (`\r` or `^M`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

tr is the wrong tool for the job; try something else (like sed)

---

tr (text replace) only does 1:1 replacement - so it will only replace one character, with another, at a time. I think your current command replaces > with /n, >> with /n/n, >>> with /n/n/n and >>>> with /n/n/n/n.

try using sed instead, probably something like this (untested!):

```
cat input | sed $'s/>/\\\n\\\n\\\n\\\n/g' > output
```

Comment: OS X's version of `sed` doesn't interpret escape sequences like `\n`, but you can use `$'...'` to make the shell interpret them before handing them to `sed`. And then you have to escape the newlines to keep `sed` happy, and escape *those* escapes to get the shell to pass them through... it ends up looking like this: `sed $'s/>/\\\n\\\n\\\n\\\n/g' input >output`

Comment: yes or use the equivalent in awk, that does understand `\n` chars, i.e. `cat input | awk '{printf("%s\n\n\n\n", $0)}' ` (untested, but close). .... Good luck to all.